# ESLint cannot find module 'ajv' in asp.net core 2.1 VS 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, eslint, asp.net-core-2.1, libman

I have a ASP.NET Core 2.1 project in Visual Studio 2017, now I added the client side libraries using Libman(Library Manager) everything worked fine the first day, next day I get an error saying "(ESLint) cannot find module 'ajv'" plus no JavaScript code executes at the browser, any idea of how i'm going to solve this, tried everything?
[(ESLint) cannot find module 'ajv'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7CnA.png)